# React native- run android

Tags: react-native, genymotion

When placing react-native run-android it marks me this error: error The application could not be installed. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run the CLI with the --verbose flag for more details.
Error: command failed: application gradlew.bat: installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort = 8081
the emulator I am using is the Genymotion

Comment: probably your environment is not setup properly

Answer (score 0):

As it says follow the steps of setupping environment https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
Also, I can advise you to check your bash profile if you are using macOS.
Crete bash profile if it is not created by: `touch ~/.bash_profile;` in the terminal.
And after run in terminal to open `open ~/.bash_profile`